# Running, Rolling Sum in a specified window in R

Tags: r, runner, rolling-sum

I want to determine the running total of a column within a specified date window.

| id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 2023-01-01 | 1 |
| 7 | 2023-01-03 | 1 |
| 7 | 2023-01-04 | 3 |
| 7 | 2023-01-05 | 2 |
| 7 | 2023-01-06 | 1 |
| 7 | 2023-01-07 | 5 |
| 7 | 2023-01-10 | 3 |
| 7 | 2023-01-14 | 2 |
| 15 | 2023-01-01 | 1 |
| 15 | 2023-01-02 | 1 |
| 15 | 2023-01-04 | 2 |
| 15 | 2023-01-07 | 2 |
| 15 | 2023-01-12 | 1 |
| 15 | 2023-01-13 | 1 |
| 15 | 2023-01-14 | 10 |

Given the table above,
I need to determine the max rolling sum for any 7-day window for each id. (first window would 1/1 to 1/7, second 1/2-1/8, etc...)

In other words, for id 7, that's 14 for the 1/4-1/10 windows (3 + 2 + 1 + 5 + 3). For 15, that's 12 for the 1/8-1/14 window (1 + 1 + 10).

I was using the runner library, but I can't quite get what I should be getting.

Edit:
This worked if the max is not in the first few windows:

```
library(runner)

df %>%
group_by(id) %>%
mutate(rsum = runner(value, k=7, idx=date, f=function(x) sum(x), na_pad=T)) %>%
filter(!is.na(rsum)) %>%
summrise(max_rsum = max(rsum))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rollapplyr` takes as arguments the value, vector of widths (how many values to sum at each point) and the function to apply (`sum`).   Run that for each group and then take the maximum.

```
library(dplyr, exclude = c("filter", "lag"))
library(zoo)

df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>% # can omit if already Date class
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(max = rollapplyr(value, 1:n() - findInterval(date - 7, date), sum)) %>%
  slice_max(max) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-value)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
# Groups:   id [2]
     id date         max
  <int> <date>     <int>
1     7 2023-01-10    14
2    15 2023-01-14    12
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L), date = c("2023-01-01", "2023-01-03", 
"2023-01-04", "2023-01-05", "2023-01-06", "2023-01-07", "2023-01-10", 
"2023-01-14", "2023-01-01", "2023-01-02", "2023-01-04", "2023-01-07", 
"2023-01-12", "2023-01-13", "2023-01-14"), value = c(1L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 10L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach assumes that each date value is unique within the group it falls in. It involves using `complete()` to add "dummy" records for each missing day/date that falls within the date range for each group. Doing so means 7 rows == 1 week. Rolling sums for each 7 day period (e.g. 7 rows) can then be calculated using `roll_sum()` from the `RcppRoll` package. As an example of the desired output was not provided, it is assumed a summary tibble is sufficient:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(RcppRoll)

# Your example table as a dataframe
df <- read.table(text = "id     date    value
7   2023-01-01  1
7   2023-01-03  1
7   2023-01-04  3
7   2023-01-05  2
7   2023-01-06  1
7   2023-01-07  5
7   2023-01-10  3
7   2023-01-14  2
15  2023-01-01  1
15  2023-01-02  1
15  2023-01-04  2
15  2023-01-07  2
15  2023-01-12  1
15  2023-01-13  1
15  2023-01-14  10", header = T)
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)

df %>% 
  arrange(id, date) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  complete(date = full_seq(date, 1), fill = list(value = 0)) %>%
  mutate(max_7day_rollsum = roll_sum(value, 7, align = "right", fill = 0)) %>%
  filter(max_7day_rollsum == max(max_7day_rollsum)) %>%
  select(-value)
```

and the result:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
# Groups:   id [2]
     id date       max_7day_rollsum
  <int> <date>                <dbl>
1     7 2023-01-10               14
2    15 2023-01-14               12
```